# Ordering by meta key with pre_get_posts leaves out posts without the metakey

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite

I am able to display posts ordered by custom meta key using the `pre_get_posts` action. How ever, it is leaving out (not displaying) posts without this meta key. Is there any way to display the posts with out the meta key at the end?

```
$q->set( 'meta_key', '_1m_e_date' );
$q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
$q->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
```

Thank you

Comment: I believe this might be expected behaviour

Comment: Yes sir. The question is: Is there any way to display the posts with out the meta key at the end?

Comment: maybe a meta query with both EXISTS and NOT EXISTS clauses.